# How to run multiple commands with gosu in Kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes, command, jobs, libgosu

I am defining a Kubernetes job to run a rake task but stuck in how to write the command...

I am new to K8s and trying to run a Rails application in K8s. 
In my Rails app Dockerfile, I created a user , copied code to /home/abc and installed rvm and rails in this user, and also specified an entrypoint and command:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/abc/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD bash -l -c "cd /home/abc && rvm use 2.2.10 --default && rake db:migrate && exec /usr/bin/supervisord -c config/supervisord.conf"
```

In docker-entrypoint.sh, the last command is

```
exec gosu abc "$@"
```

The goal is to at the end, gosu to user abc, and then run db migration and start the server through supervisord. It works, although I dont know whether it is a good practice or not...

Now I would like to run another rake task for some purpose. 
Firstly, I tried to run it using kubectl exec command:

```
kubectl exec my-app-deployment-xxxx -- gosu abc bash -l -c 'cd /home/abc && rvm use 2.2.10 --default && rake app:init:test_task'
```

It worked, but it requires to know the pod id, which is dynamic. so I tried to create a K8s job and specify in the command:

```
containers:
- name: my-app
  image: my-app:v0.2
  command: 
  - "gosu"
  - "abc"
  - "bash -l -c 'cd /home/abc && rvm use 2.2.10 --default && rake app:init:test_task'"
```

I expect the job can be completed successfully, but it failed, and the error info when kubectl logs job_pod is like:

> error: exec: "bash -l -c 'cd /home/abc && rvm use 2.2.10 --default && rake app:init:test_task'": stat bash -l -c cd /home/abc && rvm use 2.2.10 --default && rake app:init:test_task': no such file or directory

I think it should be because of how to write the 'command' part to run multiple commands with gosu...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `gosu` takes the user name and the Bash shell as arguments, I'd say that this is one rather than three separate commands.

Given that, there can be only one single `entrypoint` in each container, you can try running it as follows:

```
containers:
- name: my-app
 image: my-app:v0.2
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "gosu username bash -l -c 'cd /home/abc && rvm use 2.2.10 --default && rake app:init:test_task'"]
```

Notice that you have to spawn a new TTY in order to run the command as [the image's `entrypoint` is replaced when running commands in the container spec in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes).

Comment: Thanks a lot! just back from a sick leave.... May I ask a naive question that why need to spawn a new TTY when the endpoint is replaced? thanks!